Movie made by Gnostic sect which disturbs all who see it
I'm trying to remember a movie. It was black and white, the language being English.
The protagonist stumbles upon a movie in a theatre that somehow disturbs all those who see it. I forget the middle but towards the end our anti-hero finds out that Gnostics in some remote sect concocted the scheme.
Said gnostics were responsible for the movie's creation to speed up the coming of the apocalypse (I don't remember if it's referred to as "immanentizing the eschaton").
The movie becomes an overnight sensation, everyone watches it and at the very end we're left to believe the end of the world occurred.

It sounds a lot like Flicker, but it isn't a movie yet. I'd like to see this movie, though.

Is it possible you've confused a few things (or that this answer is wrong)?
It sounds like John Carpenter's In the Mouth of Madness: he stumbles upon a movie in a theatre that somehow disturbs all those who see it.
Illuminatus!, utilized the phrase "immanentize the eschaton," but there was never a movie was there? 
The novel Flicker is a candidate for its cult speeding up the apocalypse using signals hidden in movies. Supposedly soon to be a moving picture for a long time now.

had a dream about Flicker that i confused for a movie. I havent read it in ages, thanks buddy

Flicker might be my favorite novel. No worries. (Cosmic Banditos, Illuminatus!, Trout Fishing in America, The Fan Man, etc, so many choices!)
